# How do I add static variables to a class dynamically without an object

Tags: python, types, static, attributes

I am using FastAPI. I considered asking Tiangolo about this directly but I think it is a Python question TBH so I'm asking here first.

Currently, I have a file called countries.py as follows:

```
from enum import Enum
    

class Countries(str, Enum):
    AF = "AF"
    AX = "AX"
    AL = "AL"
    DZ = "DZ"
    AS = "AS"
```

In my model file I have this code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

from .countries import Countries


class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    countryInQuestion: Countries
```

Now what I really want to be able to do is something like setattr (which is only available on objects) but on the static class to define the countries.

Something along the lines of:

```
from country_list import countries_for_language

countries = dict(countries_for_language('en'))
```

and in the model I would want to somehow apply the dict as follows:

```
{k:k for k in countries.keys()}
```

Comment: assigning `{k:k for k in countries.keys()}` to a variable on class `SomeModel` does not work?

Comment: I don't want to do that I want multiple variables each with the keys as names and assigned strings which are the k's.  All the variables should be within the class, not an object.